# Deleting elements in Python list using user input

Tags: python

```
name=input("Enter your name: ")
message=input("Enter your message:")
namefinal=list(name)

for namefinal in message:
     del(namefinal)
     print(message)
```

I need help with creating a program that gets a message from the user and removes all of the letters that are in the user’s name. I made the user `input(name)` into a list but I don't know how to delete the letters. For example if I type in `Charan` and the message is `Lebron James` it will delete r,a,and n from Lebron James, making it `Lebo Jmes`.

Comment: Please add your own logic attempt in the code snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have reformatted your title.  Please provide the code you have attempted in the future.  It helps others to help you faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
name=input("Enter your name: ")
message=input("Enter your message:")
namefinal = ''
for letter  in name:   
   if letter not in message:
       namefinal += letter
print namefinal
```

Comment: can u tell me what for loop does

Comment: lik explain each line in the for loop

Comment: for loop of line 4 iterates each letter in  name string,and then verify if the letter is  not in message

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace, to remove letters:

```
for letter in name:
    message = message.replace(letter, '')
```